# Export Kendo Grid to Excel in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I need to export webgrid data into excel, I am using mvc 5 application.click the button, webgrid data into export into excel file. webgrid generated dynamic data, 
here is my view code.

```
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("grid")
        .Scrollable()
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.AutoGenerate(column =>
            {
                column.Width = "100px";
            });

         })
         .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 900px;" })
         .Groupable()
         .Filterable()
         .Sortable(sortable => sortable
             .AllowUnsort(true)
             .SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn)
          )
         .Pageable(pageable => pageable
             .PageSizes(true)
          )
         .Resizable(resize => resize
             .Columns(true)
          )
         .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
             .Ajax()
             .PageSize(20)
             .ServerOperation(false)
          )
      )
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question ?  Are you wanting someone to write you the code to export a kendo grid to excel for you ?

Comment: I added my view code.

Answer (score 1):

The easier way to go about it, would be to use the KendoUI Grid's built-in ability to export to Excel.
Just add the excel button to the toolbar with a

```
.ToolBar(tools => tools.Excel())
```

and then add the Excel configuration

```
.Excel(excel => excel
    .FilterName("My Kendo Grid Export.xlsx")
    .Filterable(true)
)
```

See official telerik sample at [KendoUI Demos Site](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/excel-export)

If you need to support older than IE10 or Safari, you will need to make use of the ProxyURL configuration.  See documentation at [KendoUI Documentation and API Reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-excel)

Your other options is creating the spreadsheet using server side controls, ala GemBox ([Gembox Excel File Creation Sample](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/support/articles/create-xls-xlsx-ods-csv-html-net)) or the Microsoft Office Excel Object Library ([MS Office Object Library Sample](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-create-excel.htm)) or any number of other alternatives which have a litany of Stack Overflow Q/A already ([Stackoverflow Search for '.Net create Excel file'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=.net%20create%20excel%20file)).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this. I got an error: does not contain definition for excel in kendo and no extension method

Comment: Which version of KendoUI are you using ? I think the native export to excel was added in the first 2015 release.

Comment: Version 2014.1.528.545

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest version.

Comment: how can I upgrade  to the latest version?

Comment: Go and download it from the vendors site.

Comment: Can you please give me the link

Comment: How to add kendoui in project. there is no Kendo.MVC dll

Comment: This has now gone way beyond the scope of your initial question.  If you have additional questions about Visual Studio (or whatever IDE you are using) and using DLLs, please create another question.

Comment: Export to Excel button not working. when i click, button color changes to orange color

Comment: Is there anything in the browser console as far as an error goes ?  Is there a callback to the server? Which browser/version are you using ?

Comment: this is  I found in Console.   

HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
    File: RunReports
    DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more        information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
    File: RunReports
    HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
    File: localhost:11040
    DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more  information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337

Comment: Since you are using their MVC controls and grid, I would switch over to the professional help from Telerik.

Answer (score 0):

It display data only in one excel sheet. I need to display 20 records in each excel sheet.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#export").click(function (e) {
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

        grid.saveAsExcel();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```